# Spring hibernate more than one row with the given foreign key was found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i have a problem using `findByProfileId()` method of JPA repository

this is my sample entries (rows) on my database.

[image]

When i try to request via REST (http://localhost:8080/rest/test/21234) where **21234** is the profile_id in the above table.

Here is my RESTservice.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable Long id){
    try {
        logger.info("get({})",id);
        logger.info("get({})",Lists.transform(wishlistService.get(id), toRestWishlist));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Lists.transform(wishlistService.get(id), toRestWishlist), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        logger.error("{}",e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Here is the **WishlistServiceImpl**

```
@Override
public List<Wishlist> get(Long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return repo.findByProfileId(id);
}
```

Here is the Repository

```
@Repository
public interface WishlistRepository extends JpaRepository<Wishlist, Long> {

    List<Wishlist> findByProfileId(Long id);

}
```

Here is my `Wishlist` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wishlist")
public class Wishlist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="wish_Id")
    private Long wishId;

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    private Profile profile;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "wishlist", 
        cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, 
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="images")
    private String images;

    @Column(name="created_at")
    private Long createAt;

    @Column(name="updated_at")
    private Long updatedAt;

    /* Getters and Setters and toString() */

}
```

Everytime i send the request i get this error on the logs

```
2017-12-08 14:15:54.854  INFO 2620 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.s.s.web.controller.WishlistController  : get(21234)
2017-12-08 14:15:54.858  INFO 2620 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 21234, for class: com.secret.santa.core.models.Wishlist
2017-12-08 14:15:54.858 ERROR 2620 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.s.s.web.controller.WishlistController  : More than one row with the given identifier was found: 21234, for class: com.secret.santa.core.models.Wishlist; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 21234, for class: com.secret.santa.core.models.Wishlist
```

Comment: `@Query('select w from Wishlist w where w.profile_id=?1')` you can try query method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare method signature in `Repository` as:

```
List<Wishlist> findAllByProfile(Profile profile);
```

And you have to pass something like `new Profile(profileId)`.

Also, you might have to change `@OneToOne` annotation in field `Profile` to `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: changed the paramter from `id` to `profileId`. error still the same

Comment: tried using `findAllByProfileId`, still the more than one row error occurred

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: tried applying you answer. changed my repository to accept `Profile` class and in my service i change the way i use it to `return repo.findAllByProfile(new Profile(id));`. error still the same

Comment: So, I believe the error comes from `@OneToOne` annotation. Maybe you have to change it into `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: Yes, i have assigned incorrect relationship between classes